# woocommerce {{{ data.variation }}} as variable

Tags: php, syntax, woocommerce

**New Question:**

Does anyone know how to work with {{{ data.variation }}} in the woocommerce template variation.php?

If I use: {{{ data.variation.variation_id }}} I get an ID printed as 55 (in variables.php, for a selected variation that actually has the ID of 55).

If I use: get_post_meta( '55', '_start_month', true ) I get the variation data that I am looking for.

But (*and here is the confusion*) if I use

```
get_post_meta( '{{{ data.variation.variation_id }}}', '_start_month', true )
```

I get null. I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the {{{ data.variation }}} values as numbers.

Argh!!

**Previous Question:**

I am working in the woocommerce template variation.php.

It has code that includes:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmps-variation-template">
{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}
</script>
```

This renders the price for a product variation. I have modified it to pull another variation like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmps-variation-template">
{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}
{{{ data.variation.my_number }}}
</script>
```

I am then able to pull this into php like this:

```
$var="{{{ data.variation.my_number }}}";
echo $var;
```

This shows me the variation value. In this case it is 14.

So, it would seem that I have a value that is accessible to php. But it isn't. I cannot do anything with the value. I can't turn it from a string into an integer or anything like that. For example.

```
$var=$var * 2;
```

Or:

```
$var= (int) $var;
$var=$var * 2;
```

Spits out '0';

To investigate, I did a var_dump.

```
var_dump($var);
```

This shows me that $var is 24 characters long. In other words, I was expecting the value of var_dump($var) to be 2 characters long (the value '14'), but instead var_dump($var) seems to be calculating 'data.variation.my_number' as the value.

So, while it looks like $var=14 it seems to actually be that $var='data.variation.my_number';

I have rewritten this question to try to be more clear. But I think it might still be confusing. The php variable value seems to be the variation name, not the variation value.

Is there any php syntax that I can use to separate one from the other?

Thanks for any insight. I'm hoping this is a quickie for someone who knows of the right method or syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't $var = data.variation.price_html work? (as I'm assuming the curly brackets just echo out the content)

Comment: The curly brackets seem required to get a value.

Comment: I was never able to figure this out. I was trying to get woocomerce variation data and then use it. I began by using Remi Corson's approach: http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/ and ended up beating my head against the wall. I ended up using Pramod Pandey's approach https://medium.com/wordpress-knowledge/display-woocommerce-product-variation-in-table-instead-of-drop-down-4b7d31f12987. This has worked out very well for my needs. I don't love the idea of having page layouts so tied to my functions file, but this did solve my needs.

Answer (score 0):

so I've just been faced with the same problem, wanting to control or have some conditional logic around the output of {{{ data.variation.checkbox }}} within variation.php and found that we can use this:

```
<# if ( data.variation.checkbox == 'yes') { #>
    <div>YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
<# } #>
```

the code uses the wp.template - works like a treat.
reference from where this was taken.

https://zao.is/blog/2017/03/22/how-to-use-wp-template/

hope it helps